# handle the total of Integers exceeding Long

Tags: vb6, overflow

I have the following code :

```
Dim L as Integer
Dim R as Integer
Dim a as Integer

a=((L+R)/2)
```

---

Now `(L+R)` exceeds limit of `Integer`.
In order to handle this case:
I have following three options:

1. Define L (or R) as `Long`
2. Write `a= ((CLng(L)+R)/2)`
3. Declare new variable as `Long` :

Like this

```
Dim S as Long
S=S+L+R
```

---

I am confused which one is the best to implement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd pick #2. I think (not sure) that this uses a little less memory than #1 because there's only one Long -value in the equation where as changing L or R to Long would require space for 2 Long values.

I'm thinking #2 and #3 might end up looking the same (or pretty damn close) after compile and I personally think that in this case an extra variable wouldn't make it more readable. The difference of course is that in #2 the result of the L+R might not need to be saved anywhere, but only moved between registers for the calculation.

I'm thinking alot here, but I'm posting this partly because I hope that if I'm wrong, someone would correct me. Anyway, with the reasoning above, I'd go with #2. Edit: at least I'm quite certain that if one of the options uses less memory than the others, it's #2, but they might all be the same in that regard.

Comment: Thanks pkauko for sharing you thoughts

Comment: Alhtough I must say I don't disagree with MarkJ in the least, so I'd say you should do as he suggests assuming you're not extremely tight on memory (in which case you'd probably be coding in C or some such) or, as he says, there are millions of instances of these variables in use simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

Change all the variables to `Long`.

- The code will be **more robust**.
- The code will **execute faster**.
- The additional 2 bytes of memory per variable is **totally insignificant**, unless you have *many* millions of these integer variables in use simultaneously.

You've already posted several questions here about integer overflow errors. With all respect, I really advise you to just change **all** your `Integer` variables to `Long` and get on with your coding.